# Getting 403 error when form is submitted

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have looked for similar topics but the 403 error seems to be caused by the form values, but not in my case.

I only get the 403 error when my htaccess looks like this:

```
AuthUserFile /homepages/11/d539801920/htdocs/sevigne/.htpasswd
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
<limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit> 
Allow from 82.67.108.47
Deny from All
Satisfy Any

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I delete the first part (that denies/allows access), it works fine. 
I don't know if it matters but the form is created using CodeIgniter's form helper ("echo form_open_multipart('restauration/rate');")

I solved a similar issue by sending HTTP headers when using a file_get_contents(file, false, headers), but I don't know how to deal with that one. :/

Comment: If I only delete the three lines "Allow... Deny ... Satisfy Any" it works as well. So the issue is there...

Comment: you should Deny before allow

Comment: Let me guess: You are sending your form with method POST, but your `<LIMIT>` section only applies to requests made via GET – and so the only thing to `SATISFY` here is that access will be granted if the requesting IP is `82.67.108.47`, but in any other case the request will be `DENY`-ed …

Comment: Already tried Dragon.
That was spot on CBroe, I'm sorry if this was obvious, I'm pretty new to this Apache "programming". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you CBRoe for the answer which lies in the  section of the .htaccess
It needs to be `<limit GET POST>` and not just `<limit GET>` . Obvious when you look at it like that...